# pdftk: Too many heap sections: Increase MAXHINCR or MAX_HEAP_SECTS

Tags: pdftk

I was trying to combine 10 pdfs. The total pages are around 100,000 pages.

I am using

```
pdftk 1.pdf ... 10.pdf output total.pdf
```

the total size of pdf will be around 300+mb.

I get the following error

`Too many heap sections: Increase MAXHINCR or MAX_HEAP_SECTS`

How can i increase `MAXHINCR or MAX_HEAP_SECTS`

Comment: What use is a TEN MILLION page `pdf`? Try adding them 1 at a time.

Comment: Sorry its `100,000` pages. So you mean I should try to club two at a time and keep apending one more pdf

Comment: "club"? What does "club" mean?

Answer (score 1):

The values in the error message are set at compile time, so they're useful only if you're building from source.

I suggest you add the `.pdf` files one at a time.

Something like

```
for i in $(seq 1 10); do
   if [[ $i -eq 1 ]] ; then
        cp $i.pdf a.tmp.pdf
    else
        pdftk a.tmp.pdf $i.pdf output b.tmp.pdf
        mv b.tmp.pdf a.tmp.pdf
    fi
done
mv a.tmp.pdf total.pdf
```

**Warning** I have not tried this.

Comment: I will check this

Comment: I am using now `stapler` it does not give any error

Comment: this is slower and  could not try till end